# Solution verification on a Borel Cantelli Exercise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

I have a question regarding the following exercise that I just solved.

> Let $(X_n)$ be any sequence of random variables, show that there exists a sequence of positive constants $(l_n)$ such that one has
> $$
> P(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_n}{l_n} = 0).
> $$

**Solution**: Getting started, there exists a sequence of $(l_n)$ such that for every $n \in \mathbb N$ one has $P(|l_n X_n| \geq 1/n) \leq 1/n^2$. Indeed applying the Markov inequality one has
$$
P(|l_n X_n| \geq 1/n) \leq l_n E[|X_n|] n \leq 1/n^2,
$$
if one chooses $l_n \leq \frac{1}{E[X_n] n^3}$. Now to finish the proof it sufficies to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ one has
$$
P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|X_n|}{l_n} \geq \epsilon) = 0.
$$
We are going to apply a Borel-Cantelli argument, for this observe that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that one has $\epsilon > 1/n$, applying this one observation in combination with the prior estimate yields that
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} P(\frac{X_n}{l_n} \geq \epsilon) \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} P(\frac{X_n}{l_n} \geq 1/n) \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} 1/n^2 < \infty,
$$
Hence by the first Borel Cantelli lemma one has that
$$
P(\limsup_{n \to \infty} |X_n| /l_n \geq \epsilon) = 0,
$$
and this sufficies.

**Question**: Is this reasoning, especially the choice of $(l_n)$ correct? What if one takes $X_n = + \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ as this should be allowed for random variables.

Comment: 1. The choice of $l_n$ is fine. 2.  You cannot allow $X_n=\infty$. The result  simply false in that case. 3. You still need  a little argument at the end to finish the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two (slight) mistakes. Also, you need to state that $X_{n}$'s are integrable if you are planning to use Markov's Inequality.

Firstly, you fix $\epsilon$ and then say

> $$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} P(\frac{X_n}{l_n} \geq \epsilon) \leq
>  \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} P(\frac{X_n}{l_n} \geq 1/n) \leq \sum_{n \in
> > \mathbb N} 1/n^2 < \infty, $$

No. This is not true.

What you need to do is say that there exists $N_{0}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ for all $n> N_{0}$

Hence $P(|\frac{X_{n}}{l_{n}}|\geq\epsilon)\leq P(|\frac{X_{n}}{l_{n}}|\geq\frac{1}{n})\leq \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ for all $n>N_{0}$.

Hence \begin{align} \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} P(|\frac{X_n}{l_n}| \geq \epsilon)&=\sum_{k=1}^{N_{0}}P(|\frac{X_n}{l_n}|
\geq \epsilon)+\sum_{k=N_{0}+1}^{\infty}P(|\frac{X_n}{l_n}| \geq \epsilon)\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{N_{0}}P(|\frac{X_n}{l_n}| \geq \epsilon)+\sum_{n\geq N_{0}+1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty \end{align}

And this is true for all $\epsilon>0$.

Now you set $B_{\epsilon}=\{|\frac{X_{n}}{l_{n}}|\geq\epsilon\,\text{infinitely often}\}=\{\limsup_{n \to \infty} |X_n| /l_n \geq \epsilon\}$

Now you take $B=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_{\frac{1}{n}}$ and by what we(you) did, $P(B)=0$ or equivalently $P(B^{c})=1$

Now show that for any $\omega\notin B$ or equivalently for any $\omega\in B^{c}$ which is a set of probability $1$, you have that $\frac{X_{k}(\omega)}{l_{k}}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}0$.

Note that the last step that I did above is basically showing this useful reslt:
If $X_{n},X$ be random variables such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\Bbb{N}}P(|X_{n}-X|>\epsilon)<\infty$ for each $\epsilon$ then $X_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}X$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer it was super helpful, but I am not sure why you need the extra event $B$ and not just $B_{\epsilon}$, did you not already argue that for all $\epsilon > 0$ one has $P(B_{\epsilon}) = 1$, thus $P(\cap_{\epsilon > 0} B_{\epsilon}) = 1$,  so one has $1 = P(\cap_{\epsilon > 0} \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|X_n|}{l_n} < \epsilon) \leq (\cap_{\epsilon > 0} \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{|X_n|}{l_n} = 0) \leq P(\lim_{n \to \infty \frac{|X_n|{l_n} = 0)$, since the intersection of arbitary probability 1-events have probability one (use subadditivity of P).

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent Can you check your comment again, the code has not rendered properly. Perhaps you can edit it. But as far as I can make out from your comment, You cannot consider $P(\cap_{\epsilon>0}B_{\epsilon})$ as this is an intersection of uncountably many sets and it need not lie in the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ in which $P$ is defined. Instead, you move to a countable union/intersection by taking a sequence decreasing to $0$ (I like $\frac{1}{n}$ but any other sequence works).

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent Secondly, your inequalities (not understandable properly) seem to be false. You have $P(\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\lim\sup\frac{|X_{n}|}{l_{n}}<\frac{1}{n})=P(\lim\sup\frac{|X_{n}|}{l_{n}}=0)$ . Also note that I had considered (in my answer) $B_{\epsilon}=\{\lim\sup \frac{|X_{n}|}{l_{n}}\geq \epsilon\}$ and not $\{\lim\sup \frac{|X_{n}|}{l_{n}}< \epsilon\}$ as you and I have done now in the comments.

Comment: Also one has to justify why $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}\{\lim\sup \frac{|X_{n}|}{l_{n}}<\epsilon\}=\bigcap_{n}\{\lim\sup \frac{|X_{n}|}{l_{n}}<1/n\}=\{\lim\sup\frac{|X_{n}|}{l_{n}}=0\}$ which is just a real analysis argument.

Comment: Allright I forgot about the fact that it might not lie in the sigma algebra, I am going to edit my post later providing the necessary details.

Comment: If your question has been answered then it is common courtesy to mark as answer and remove the question form the unanswered tab. @a.s.graduatestudent